# How to transform an image in SVG (or CSS) into a non-parallelogram shape?

Tags: css, image, svg, transform

I want to be able to create an SVG that has a (normal) image in the background and a different smaller image somewhere that has the 4 "edges" shifted to create a non-rectangular shape.  Think similar to an image distorted to create a perspective view.

Is it possible in SVG? If not, is it possible in CSS in a way that will be visible in a non fixed element of the page?

I found some CSS perspective but it uses X,Y,Z, when I really only need to fit (distort) an image in a predefined non-parallel sided "box".

Comment: SVG is 2d only. Sounds like the CSS perspective property is what you want.

Comment: Not sure why i am getting negative votes..

Comment: @RobertLongson, Thank you, I know about SVG being 2d, I was trying to figure out if there was a way to move the edges to give that impression

Comment: The downvotes maay be for lack of research effort. I.e. are there solutions you've tried and discarded for one reason or another?

Comment: Haven't found ANYTHING.  I found some CSS perspective but it uses X,Y,Z, when I really only need to fit an image in a predefined non equal sided "box"

Comment: Fit it how? By distorting it or clipping it. If it's by distorting it then you wan't a non-affine transformation and there's nothing that does that for you.

Comment: DIstorting it.  Don't want something that does it for me.. I want to figure out how to do it, but now that I know the name I will go back to Google, unless you have done handy links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, theoretically, a way to create the type of distortion you need using SVG 1.1.  It relies on the [`<feDisplacementMap>` filter element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feDisplacementMapElement).

I include sample code below if you want to explore it.  However, I wouldn't recommend it as anything other than a curiosity; from my testing, the code currently only gives the desired result in Chrome (and probably related browsers). Internet Explorer distorts the image, but slightly differently.  I actually had it working with slightly different code in I.E., but not in Chrome.  Firefox doesn't support the use of `<feImage>` filter elements to import fragments from the SVG, so the test case fails; it should work if you created the map gradient as a separate image file.  There also is simply the poor rendering quality, because you're distorting the image using pixel manipulation.

```css
linearGradient {
  color-interpolation:linearRGB;
}
```

```html
<svg height="400px" width="400px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="red-grad" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#F00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#000" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="mask-grad" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
    
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect fill="url(#mask-grad)" 
            height="100%" width="100%"/>
    </mask>
    <rect id="red-rect" fill="url(#red-grad)" mask="url(#mask)"
          height="100%" width="100%"/>
    
    <filter id="perspective" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox"
            x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
      <feImage xlink:href="#red-rect" result="red" />
      <feFlood flood-color="black" result="black" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in="red" in2="black" 
                   result="map"/>
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" in2="map"
                         yChannelSelector="R"
                         xChannelSelector="G"
                         scale="1.1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
<g style="opacity:0.5">
  <image id="pic" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Iglesia_de_Santiago_Tlatelolco%2C_M%C3%A9xico_D.F.%2C_M%C3%A9xico%2C_2013-10-16%2C_DD_38.JPG/320px-Iglesia_de_Santiago_Tlatelolco%2C_M%C3%A9xico_D.F.%2C_M%C3%A9xico%2C_2013-10-16%2C_DD_38.JPG"
  />
</g>
<g transform="scale(0.7 0.5)skewY(4)">
  <use y="25%" xlink:href="#pic" filter="url(#perspective)" />
</g>
</svg>
<p>Image by <a href="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Iglesia_de_Santiago_Tlatelolco,_M%C3%A9xico_D.F.,_M%C3%A9xico,_2013-10-16,_DD_38.JPG">Diego Dielso, via Wikimedia Commons.</a></p>
```

Instead, the best approach, as Robert Longson suggested in the comments, is to use [3D transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#three-d-transform-functions) to create a perspective effect.  Most browsers (latest versions) now support 3D transforms on HTML images, although you need to duplicate the declarations with the -webkit- prefix.

Many browsers (I.E. is the exception) will also support 3D transforms on SVG elements if you declare them in the CSS code.  However, the `transform-origin` property is not well supported for SVG; it's best to leave it as the default (the SVG coordinate system origin, the same as SVG1.1 transforms), and use other transformations to get the effect you want.

---

Explanation of the snippet, for those who are curious:

1. The two gradients, mask, rectangle, and first three filter elements are all just a way to create a two-dimensional black to red gradient (red in the top-right corner, black on the left and bottom.  This is where IE has the problem -- the different elements aren't sized correctly, so most of the image ends up black.  I had to set the `color-interpolation` property to `linearRGB` so that the value of the red channel increases smoothly based on the numerical value, instead of being gamma corrected.  As mentioned above, you could create the map gradient as a separate image file, and import it into the filter with a single `<feImage>` element, and then Firefox would also support the effect.
2. The `feDisplacementMap` filter element takes every pixel in the `in` graphic, and moves it according to the color values of the corresponding pixel in the `in2` graphic (the black and red gradient).  The y displacement is set to use the red value of the map, while the x displacement uses the green value (which will be zero for the entire red-black gradient).
3. The first image element is the semi-transparent background.
4. This image is then duplicated in a `<use>` element, and the filter applied.  An additional set of transformations is used to scale the image and adjust the overall tilt (skew) so that the perspective distortion looks fairly centered.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I'll correct that.  Confession: "389746 – Implement feDisplacementMap - Bugzilla - Mozilla" was one of the top google results for "fedisplacementmap support", and I didn't even click through to confirm that it had been closed (with your patch) in 2007!

Comment: Not my patch, I was the reviewer for that one. I wrote the tile filter FWIW.